# Angular: FormControl valueChanges Observable triggers for all changes

Tags: angular, input, autosuggest

FormControl `valueChanges` Observable works like how it should be. In my case, I need to stop triggering `valueChanges` for all previous changes in input field except the current value. I have been trying with following code to do that -

```
private getAutocompleteSuggestions(input){
    return this.SS.searchProducts(parseInt(this.filter), '', input);
}


private searchSuggestionsAPIRequest(input){
    this.queryField.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((input) =>  this.getAutocompleteSuggestions(input))
        .subscribe( res => {
          // The res is triggered for all value changes in 
          // queryField formcontrol

          // Tried with following solution to stop emit previous 
          // changes but it does not work

          this.queryField.setValue(input, { emitEvent: false });

    });
}
```

I have been searching for all possible ways to stop emit previous values, but got this solution -

```
this.queryField.setValue(input, { emitEvent: false });
```

I think, I am missing something there. It would be great if there is any further solution or documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a possibility that you are trying to achieve something in a different way, could you explain your scenario when you say  "you want to ignore previous values".

Answer (score 0):

ValueChange is an observale and everytime you make an input it will going to trigger the emit. You can call you api in switch map and subscribe its result to there with the latest value from input and leave valueChanges behaviour as it is.

```
searchBook() {
    this.bookId.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(input => {
        this.getAutocompleteSuggestions(input)).subscribe(res =>{
          //DO you required processing
        })
      })
    ).subscribe(model => model);
   }
```